# How do I get a count of each of the words in my list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
 X = ['raz', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'cztery']
```

and want Output:

```
{'cztery': 1, 'dwa': 2, 'raz': 3, 'trzy': 2}
```

Comment: @Brian Can you write an answer demonstrating that?

Comment: @tcaswell: I just wrote an answer using `groupby`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> lst = ['raz', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'cztery']
>>> {x:lst.count(x) for x in set(lst)}
{'raz': 3, 'cztery': 1, 'dwa': 2, 'trzy': 2}
>>>
```

or, you can use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(lst)
Counter({'raz': 3, 'dwa': 2, 'trzy': 2, 'cztery': 1})
>>>
```

The second solution is probably what you want because it does the same thing as the comprehension, is more efficient, and also uses the `Counter` class, which comes with a lot of great tools (e.g. [`most_common`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) and [`subtract`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.subtract)).

Comment: @Downvoter - Please leave a reason you downvoted.  I care a lot about the quality of my work.  Hence, if you have found something wrong with my post, please let me know so I can address it.

Answer (score 1):

Another method using stdlib:

```
In [6]: from collections import Counter
In [7]: l = ['raz', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'cztery']
In [8]: dict(Counter(l).items())
Out[8]: {'cztery': 1, 'dwa': 2, 'raz': 3, 'trzy': 2}
```

Comment: Err, downvoted for what reason? Gotta love the SE community at times :P

Answer (score 0):

Just demonstrating the version with `groupby` that Brian suggested.

```
import itertools
data = ['raz', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'dwa', 'raz', 'trzy', 'cztery']
print({k:len(list(v)) for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(data))})
```

Comment: This is `O(NLogN)` in complexity.

Comment: It was a demonstration. I didn't say it was a good solution. :-)